# Listen to Angular2 Component Events

Tags: angular, typescript

Angular2 documentation is only about creating new applications, but there is nothing about using angular2 to add isolated components to an existing website. It's not an option to rewrite the complete website.
So I would like to create a simple angular component, for example something like this.

```
const template = `
    <button (click)="triggerEvent()">Trigger Event</button>
`;

@Component({
    template,
    selector: "poc-comp"
})
export class PocComponent {
    @Output() pocevent: EventEmitter<any>;
    public triggerEvent() {
        this.pocevent.emit("here we go!");
    }
}
```

then I have my hugh webpage with the component inside.

```html
<lot-of-html>
<poc-comp (pocevent)="handlerOutsideAngular()"></poc-comp>
<lot-of-other-html>
```

So that's what I thought my work but doesn't. The Event can only be catched by angular component.
My next idea was, to use `ElementRef` and use `dispatchEvent` but it looks like `ElementRef` only provides a "broken" and untyped HTMLElement.

The question is, is there any possibility to use angular for creating some kind of WebComponents that work together with Non-Angular Web-Application? Inserting data into a component is easy, but I want to get something out of the component.

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
  @Output() pocevent: EventEmitter<any>;
```

to

```
  @Output() pocevent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

---

Then,

```
<lot-of-html>
    <poc-comp (pocevent)="handlerOutsideAngular($event)"></poc-comp>   //<<<===added $event
<lot-of-other-html>


handlerOutsideAngular(value){
   console.log(value)   //here we go!
}
```

---

And I'm not sure about

```
@Component({
    template,                        <<<====This line I don't know
    selector: "poc-comp"
})
```